# Mongoose error : CastError while posting comments

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, routes

I've been trying to have a nested route to add comments to a blog. However on submitting the new comment form it gives the following error

> CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "
>   5ec68050984ae008d04685f3" at path "_id" for model "Campground"

The campground Schema is as follows

```
var campgroundSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String,
    image : String,
    description : String,
    comments : [
        {
            type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref : "Comment"
        }       
    ]
})
```

And this is the comment Schema

```
var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text : String,
    author : String
})
```

This is the code which is in the app.js file to add a new comment to a particular post

```
app.post("/campgrounds/:id", function(req,res){
    Campground.findById(req.params.id, function(err, found){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err)
                }
                else{
                    found.comments.push(comment);
                    found.save();
                    res.redirect("/campgrounds" + found._id)
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

What is wrong and how to solve it

Comment: If you read the error message will see a typo (whitespace) in your value. If you remove the whitespace, i think it will work.

Comment: I tried doing that but instead of fixing the problem, it messes up the location. Now there's no / sign between capgrounds and the id, i.e. the url shows "campgrounds5ec68e35df9bad0b4e365da4" instead

Comment: Because your redirection is missing a slash after "/campgrounds". You should do something like ("/campgrounds/"+found._id)